# Sequence Animation using NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, nstimer

good day.. I have this code.. and this two is for actionAnimating Button and stopAnimating Button..I just want to know if how to make those two button integrate in ONE button.. for example.. I click the button then it animates.. when I click again that actionAnimating Button, i want to cancel/stop the animation at the same time i want to play/animate again.. in short i want to cancel the animation when i click again the actionAnimating button..

```
-(void)flowerAnimationSequence//START ANIMATION
{
    MotherView.alpha = 0;
    flower.alpha = 0;
    [animationContainer1 removeFromSuperview];
    actselected = YES;

    NSLog(@"start");
    if (((sequenceAnimateCounter == 0) || (sequenceAnimateCounter==1)) && (actselected = YES))
    {
        aImageViewSlideShow = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        aImageViewSlideShow.tag = 171;
        [self.view addSubview:aImageViewSlideShow];

    }

    if (sequenceAnimateCounter < 183) 
    {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.035 target:self selector:@selector(flowerAnimationSequence) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }

    else if (sequenceAnimateCounter ==183) 
    {
        aImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:171];
        NSLog(@"done");
        actselected = NO;
        sequenceAnimateCounter = 0;
        [aImageView removeFromSuperview];
        aImageView = nil;
        [self DefaultPosition];
    }


    aImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:171];

    NSString *aStrNumber =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sequenceAnimateCounter];
    NSString *aBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];
    NSString *aImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sapatos_%@.png",aBundlePath,aStrNumber];

    [aImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:aImagePath]];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: aImageView];
    sequenceAnimateCounter = sequenceAnimateCounter+1;

    if (sequenceAnimateCounter == 1)
    {
        [aImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


-(void)stopanim//STOP BUTTON
{
        [timer invalidate];
        sequenceAnimateCounter =0;
        NSLog(@"stop");
        [aImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any animation code above, and I also don't see a question in your post. What animation? And what are you asking? IF you're looking for help in stopping an animation that is "in flight", you need to post animation code. All the code you posted seems to be doing is adding and removing views.

Comment: uhmm this is animating a sequence of frames.. I avoided the imageNamed: because it causes the device to crash..

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the animations built into `UIView`, `UIImage`, and `UIImageView`.

Comment: its because.. when i use the imagenamed.. the device crashes..

Comment: If imageNamed is crashing you should troubleshoot that. But I'm saying use the animationImages property on UIImageView

Answer (score 1):

Hm...

you want to start/stop in one button?

```
BOOL isAnimating = NO;

- (void)startStopAnimating 
{
    if (!isAnimating) {
       isAnimating = YES
       // start animation
    } else {
       isAnimating = NO;
       // stop animation
    }
}
```